# Python 3: How to use a While loop to remove duplicate items from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

Here is my current code:

```
sandwich_orders = ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']
finished_sandwiches = []
print("Ordered sandwiches: " , sandwich_orders)

while sandwich_orders:
    complete_sandwiches = sandwich_orders.pop()
    print("Now making your  " + complete_sandwiches.title() + "sandwich")
    finished_sandwiches.append(complete_sandwiches.title())

for finished_sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print("Your " + finished_sandwich.title() + " sandwich is now ready.")
```

This is the current program output when I run it:

```
    Ordered sandwiches:  ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']
Now making your  Pastrami sandwich
Now making your  Knuckle sandwich
Now making your  Pastrami sandwich
Now making your  Blt sandwich
Now making your  Ham sandwich
Now making your  Pastrami sandwich
Now making your  Pbj sandwich
Your Pastrami  sandwich is now ready.
Your Knuckle  sandwich is now ready.
Your Pastrami  sandwich is now ready.
Your Blt  sandwich is now ready.
Your Ham  sandwich is now ready.
Your Pastrami  sandwich is now ready.
Your Pbj  sandwich is now ready.
```

I am trying to remove all instances of 'Pastrami' from the list using a While loop, but I'm not quite sure how to format it. I tried putting this code in the while loop above

```
sandwiches = [sandwich_orders , finished_sandwiches , complete_sandwiches]
    if 'pastrami' in sandwiches:
        sandwiches.remove('pastrami')
```

And while the code runs without any errors nothing happens. I really want the output to come out like this:

> ```
> Ordered sandwiches:  ['pbj ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'knuckle ']
>
> Now making your  Knuckle sandwich
> Now making your  Blt sandwich
> Now making your  Ham sandwich
> Now making your  Pbj sandwich
> Your Knuckle  sandwich is now ready.
> Your Blt  sandwich is now ready.
> Your Ham  sandwich is now ready.
> Your Pbj  sandwich is now ready.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's space after 'pastrami' in sandwich_orders

```
sandwich_orders = ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']
```

Comment: BTW,pop() pops out elements from the last position ,and your if statement removes from the first element ,given your list's order ,the last 'pastrami' is appended to 'finished_sandwiches' before being removed

Comment: That did it. I created another 'while' loop above the first one to reference 'pastrami ' in the 'sandwich_orders' list and applied '.remove()' to the list. The lack of a space was throwing it off the entire time.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than Using a while loop, you can use the `set` datatype:

> By converting a list to `set` datatype you ensure that there will remain no duplicates in the set, as a set cannot have duplicates and finally you convert it back to list.

```
>>>a = [1,3,4,3,'a','b','a']
>>>a = list(set(a))
>>>a
>>>[1,3,4,'a','b']
>>>a.remove('a') #Now remove any element you want!
>>>a
>>>[1,3,4,'b']
```

Comment: You have removed `pastrami` from `sandwiches` but you are running while loop on `sandwich_orders` which still contains `pastrami`

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: See the answer that I posted, you first need to get rid of `pastrami ` from the `sandwich_orders`, then loop over it

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas one can:

```
sandwich_orders = ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']

# Create a pandas Series from the original list
sandwich_series =  pd.Series(sandwich_orders)

# Create a boolean series of items that were not duplicated
unique_bool = ~sandwich_series.duplicated(keep = False)
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4     True
# 5    False
# 6     True
# dtype: bool

# Select the unique items from the series
sandwich_series[unique_bool].tolist()
# ['pbj ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'knuckle ']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a new list called `new_sandwich_orders` and store `sandwich_orders` items with one appearance in it:

```
sandwich_orders = ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']
    finished_sandwiches = []
    new_sandwich_orders = []
    for s in sandwich_orders:
        if sandwich_orders.count(s) == 1:
            new_sandwich_orders.append(s)
print("Ordered sandwiches: " , new_sandwich_orders)

while new_sandwich_orders:
    complete_sandwiches = new_sandwich_orders.pop()
    print("Now making your  " + complete_sandwiches.title() + "sandwich")
    finished_sandwiches.append(complete_sandwiches.title())

for finished_sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print("Your " + finished_sandwich.title() + " sandwich is now ready.")
```

the result will be:

```
Ordered sandwiches:  ['pbj ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'knuckle ']
Now making your  Knuckle sandwich
Now making your  Blt sandwich
Now making your  Ham sandwich
Now making your  Pbj sandwich
Your Knuckle  sandwich is now ready.
Your Blt  sandwich is now ready.
Your Ham  sandwich is now ready.
Your Pbj  sandwich is now ready.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sandwich_orders = ['pbj ', 'pastrami ', 'ham ', 'blt ', 'pastrami ', 'knuckle ', 'pastrami ']

#remove all occurrence of 'pastrami ' from the sandwich_orders
sandwich_orders=[item for item in sandwich_orders if item != 'pastrami ']
finished_sandwiches = []
print("Ordered sandwiches: " , sandwich_orders)

while sandwich_orders:
    complete_sandwiches = sandwich_orders.pop()
    print("Now making your  " + complete_sandwiches.title() + "sandwich")
    finished_sandwiches.append(complete_sandwiches.title())

for finished_sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print("Your " + finished_sandwich.title() + " sandwich is now ready.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain order, you can try:

```
sandwiches = [sandwich_orders, finished_sandwiches, complete_sandwiches]
sandwiches_new = [[i for i in x if i!='pastrami'] for x in sandwiches]
```

Sets are by nature unordered.